# Change value of one result column if it is null

Tags: sql

For example I have this query

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 from mytable
```

and it returns

```
example1|null    |example3|example4|example5
examplea|exampleb|examplec|exampled|null
examplex|exampley|null    |examplexx|exampleyy
exampleh|null    |examplek|examplel|examplem
example1|example2|example3|example4|null
```

I want to replace (in the SQL statement) all values (of column5) if they are null, replacing them with 0 example. So, I want to convert the results above to *this*:

```
example1|null    |example3|example4|example5
examplea|exampleb|examplec|exampled|0
examplex|exampley|null    |examplexx|exampleyy
exampleh|null    |examplek|examplel|examplem
example1|example2|example3|example4|0
```

Is it possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ISNULL`

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4, ISNULL(column5,0) as column5
 from mytable
```

Comment: That's correct for T-SQL (MS SQL Server). Since he does not state which DB engine is being used, I'd go with `COALESCE` instead.

Comment: As well as COALESCE(), IFNULL() is also used on some servers; NVL() on others.  It is something for which there is a lot of server-specific variability.  COALESCE is the SQL Standard way of doing it, so the COALESCE recommendation is good, but not universally available.